# what is the purpose of session.lock method in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am going through [lock method](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#lock) of hibernate. I did not get what we are trying to achieve through this method.

```
 p1  = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);// person name is scott here
// here peson name got update to henry by anothet thread
session. lock(person, LockMode.READ) line 3
// still name is henry too
```

I tried  above code snippet but it did not read the person from database at line 3.
Documentation says that This may be used to perform a version check.

Not sure how does it check version and helps the developer in any scenario?

Similarly not sure what `session.lock(person, LockMode.None)` will achieve. Documentation says `LockMode.NONE` is used to  to simply re-associate a transient instance with a session.

Not sure what does it mean by reassociating a transient instance with session. A brief scenario will be a great help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The different lock-modes are meant for preventing the entity from being modified and read from multiple sources simultaneously, see the documentation entry about [pessimistic locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking) for details. In my experience, these are rarely needed, as the database isolation level usually takes care of locking as needed:

> It is not intended that users spend much time worrying about locking
>   strategies. It is usually enough to specify an isolation level for the
>   JDBC connections and then simply let the database do all the work.
>   However, advanced users may wish to obtain exclusive pessimistic locks
>   or re-obtain locks at the start of a new transaction.

As for the "reassociating a transient instance with the session" (I actually think they mean detached instance?), consider the following picture ([Hibernate entity lifecycle](http://learnertobeginner.blogspot.com/2010/07/hibernate-persistence-lifecycle.html)):

[image: Hibernate entity lifecycle]

This is the description from [Hibernate community documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview):

> Hibernate defines and supports the following object states:
>
> - Transient - an object is transient if it has just been instantiated
>     using the new operator, and it is not associated with a Hibernate
>     Session. It has no persistent representation in the database and no
>     identifier value has been assigned. Transient instances will be
>     destroyed by the garbage collector if the application does not hold a
>     reference anymore. Use the Hibernate Session to make an object
>     persistent (and let Hibernate take care of the SQL statements that
>     need to be executed for this transition).
> - Persistent - a persistent
>     instance has a representation in the database and an identifier value.
>     It might just have been saved or loaded, however, it is by definition
>     in the scope of a Session. Hibernate will detect any changes made to
>     an object in persistent state and synchronize the state with the
>     database when the unit of work completes. Developers do not execute
>     manual UPDATE statements, or DELETE statements when an object should
>     be made transient.
> - Detached - a detached instance is an object that
>     has been persistent, but its Session has been closed. The reference to
>     the object is still valid, of course, and the detached instance might
>     even be modified in this state. A detached instance can be reattached
>     to a new Session at a later point in time, making it (and all the
>     modifications) persistent again. This feature enables a programming
>     model for long running units of work that require user think-time. We
>     call them application transactions, i.e., a unit of work from the
>     point of view of the user.