# Get Hibernate Initialized object in JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a list of objects (Jpassatempos) and i'm tring to initialize them

```
       Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

       List<Jpassatempos> list = (List<Jpassatempos>) session.createQuery("select jpassatempos  from Jcodigos c where c.jconcorrentes.id=? group by c.jpassatempos.id order by c.jpassatempos.dataFim desc").setParameter(0, id).list();

       for(int i =0; i< list.size(); i++){
           Hibernate.initialize(list.get(i).getJpatrocinadoresPassatemposes());
       }


        return list;
```

and they do get populated but when i try to call them on my jsp page:

```
  ${passatempo.jpatrocinadoresPassatemposes.toArray()[0].id}
```

it gives me the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: 
...Jpassatempos.jpatrocinadoresPassatemposes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the entity structure also, i doubt you might need to initialize `getJpatrocinadoresPassatemposes()` also one by one doing iteration.

Comment: @kunal try once by renaming the org.Hibernate.Session object, because session is predefine object of HttpSession in jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your time and patience the solution was simple.
The problem was that i was getting 2 different errors and one of them was that i wasn't initializing JpatrocinadoresPassatempos correctly and then i needed to initialize it's childs like so:

Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List JpassatemposList = session.createQuery("select Jpassatempos from Jpassatempos p where p.dataFim > current_date and p.flgPago=true and p.id not in (select c.jpassatempos from Jcodigos c where c.jconcorrentes.id=? group by c.jpassatempos)  order by p.dataFim desc").setParameter(0, id).list();

```
    for(int i =0; i< JpassatemposList.size(); i++){
        Hibernate.initialize(JpassatemposList.get(i).getJpatrocinadoresPassatemposes());

        for(JpatrocinadoresPassatempos pp : JpassatemposList.get(i).getJpatrocinadoresPassatemposes()){
           Hibernate.initialize(pp.getJpatrocinadores());
        }

    }
    return JpassatemposList;
```

Once again thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

This error says : In your JSP, you can not get Hibernate session. I mean your object is not attached with session.

See hibernate life cycle for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8113456/1326692

You should pass your list from Server side to JSP like this,

```
request.setAttribute("myListName", list);
```

And then access it using JSTL.

more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2148672/1326692