# How to remove Session lock in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am using older version of Hibernate in my application. I used `session.lock(object,LOCKMODE.UPGRADE)` in my code to avoid stalestate exception. I am able to resolve the issue, but after some DB transactions, application is hanged out(my guess is DeadLock is happening). My goal is after my transaction is done I want to remove the lock on my object. How can i achieve the same.

The problems what I am facing(StaleStateException) is not because detached objects. It is due to the entity is being modified by other transactions(or threads) , before we persist into   DB. Below is our code flow.

```
DbRecord record = DAO.getBy(Id);
session.lock(record,LockMode.Upgrade);
// updating some record details and saving again into DB
session.saveOrUpdate(record)
```

My goal I want to release lock afte save or update.

Answer (score 1):

### Using .lock() to Reattach

Lock is used to save SQL/Transaction calls by putting object in detached mode.

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure()

       .buildSessionFactory();

Session sess = sf.openSession();
Transaction trx = sess.beginTransaction();

Vehicle v = (Vehicle) sess.get(Vehicle.class, 1L);

trx.commit();

sess.close();

System.out.println("vehicle now detached: " + v);



//update the vehichle outside of session when detached.

v.setVin(678);
//reattach using lock

sess = sf.openSession();

trx = sess.beginTransaction();

sess.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(v);

System.out.println("completed the update call");

trx.commit();

sess.close();

System.out.println("vehicle synchronized again: " + v);
```

And the sql Generated is as below

```
Hibernate:

    select

        vehicle0_.id as id0_0_,

        vehicle0_.make as make0_0_,

        vehicle0_.model as model0_0_,

        vehicle0_.vin as vin0_0_

    from

        Vehicle vehicle0_

   where

       vehicle0_.id=?
```

> vehicle now detached: Vehicle [id=1, make=Chevy, model=sedan, vin=345]

completed the update call

> vehicle synchronized again: Vehicle [id=1, make=Chevy, model=sedan, vin=678]

Now again you can update the lock. This will save your application from hanging.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113301/what-is-the-purpose-of-session-lock-method-in-hibernate)

Comment: Thanks for quick suggestions. The problems what I am facing(StaleStateException) is not because detached objects. It is due to the entity is being modified by other transactions(or threads) , before we persist into   DB. I modified the question